# Ubuntu LTS repository package update policy

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I recently realized that even though Ubuntu LTS is receiving 5 years of support, a lot of the packages in Ubuntu LTS package repository are not updated with the latest stable releases.

For example, `php5` package in Lucid (10.04 LTS) is at [5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/php/php5); while the same `php5` package in Precise (12.04 LTS) is at [5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php/php5).

Why the discrepancies? Update one while not updating the other despite an Ubuntu release is still being supported?

And, what are the package update policies as to whether to update a package or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update policy is for security updates and critical bugfixes only.  New upstream releases are not part of that.  This isn't an LTS-only policy; any sane distro that aims to be a stable basis for infrastructure will have a very similar policy.

Comment: I do understand that. `php5` is only an example, but probably a good one. There has been quite a few security updates from 5.3.2 to 5.3.10, why is it not being updated on 10.04 LTS?

Comment: Even the latest one [5.3.15](http://www.php.net/archive/2012.php#id2012-07-19-1) contains a security update on stream implementation.

Comment: It is being updated.  You will find that the Ubuntu package contains fixes for all of the security vulnerabilities known to exist in that version of PHP.

Comment: What does _that version_ means? For this example, they are both 5.3. I'm really curious about the policy behind this.

Comment: What is hard to understand about "that version of PHP"?

Comment: It's ambiguous because both cases in my example are of the same version - 5.3, only difference are the minor patches which some may be, and for PHP 5.3's case are, including security patches. My question is regarding how does the team decide when a security patch is good enough to be included, or when is it not.

Comment: Each minor release of PHP (e.g. 5.3.14 to 5.3.15) includes a [variety of security and bug fixes of varying severity](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php). Ubuntu LTS, Red Hat Enterprise, etc., only backport the ones they feel are the most critical.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton. 1 more question if I may, say a critical security is fixed at 5.3.13, while the current version in Lucid main repo is at 5.3.2, will the Ubuntu team fast-forwards 11 minor patches to .13; or they cherry-pick?

Comment: They cherry pick just the critical bugfixes.  PHP minor releases also contain a pile of non-critical changes, which distributions don't distribute in the name of stability.

Answer (score 4):

I've researched and found acceptable answers to my question:

Ubuntu team outlines the decisions on when or if a package should be updated at their [wiki on stable release updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).

Also, the procedures in determining if a package is worthy of a security update are outlined at the [security team update procedure](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures).

See also: [Related discussion on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)